# Trying to group results by related field using Pods Framework, WordPress

Tags: wordpress, podscms

Using WordPress and PodsFramework v2.3.18

I’m trying to query results from a pod using a related field. This field is related to a pod that is related to another pod.

Ex.

```
Episode.producer_location -> Locations
Location.license -> Licenses
License.name -> Field I want to group the Episode results by
```

Here is my setup:

3 pods:
Episodes,
Locations,
Licenses

Episodes.producer_location has a relationship with the Locations pod.
Locations.license has a relationship with the Licenses pod.

I am trying to group the results by the license name, which is related by the location to the episode.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'd be happy to answer this question, but first please tell me what content type these Pods are, as that affects the answer. Also see this thread in our forums, for the answer to a similar question: http://pods.io/forums/topic/how-can-filter-by-a-field-of-a-relation-field-of-a-relation-field-using-find/

Comment: Thanks JPollock! Your link was exactly what I needed to get my query going.